# How is $mE(K)$ injected into the reduced curve $\tilde{E}(k)$ by the reduction map?

Tags: elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

This is from Silverman's Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves:
[image: hey]

I have understood everything in this proof except the last line of part (b), which says that the $m$-torsion of $E(K)$ injects into $\tilde{E}(k)$, this is what I tried:

$mE(K)$ is contained in the kernel of the reduction map : $E_0(K)=E(K) \to  \tilde{E}_{ns}(k) = \tilde{E}(k)$ here. And this kernel is $E_1(K)$. And since, we have the injection 
$$ E(K)/E_1(K) \to \tilde{E}(k)$$
It will induce an injection
$$ E(K)/mE(K) \to \tilde{E}(k)$$

Am I right?

Any hints, corrections or suggestions are highly appreciated.
Thank you.

$E_0(K) = \{P \in E(K) : \tilde{P} \in \tilde{E}_{ns}(k) \}$
$E_1(K) = \{ P \in E(K) : \tilde{P} = \tilde{O} \}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple "yes, it holds as stated" could be the answer to the question in the OP, but to give more support i will insert some diagrams. First of all, by definitions,
Proposition 2.1 and the part (a) of Proposition 3.1. in *loc. cit.* we have:

$\require{AMScd}$
$$
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> E_1(K) @>>> E_0(K) @>>> \tilde E_{ns}(k) @>>> 0 \\
@.     @.          @VVV   \square @VVV         @. \\
  @.          @.   E(K)   @>>> \tilde E(k)
\end{CD}
$$

(The first row is a short exact sequence, the vertical arrows are inclusions.)
Now part (b) addresses the case when $\tilde E_{ns}(k) = \tilde E(k)$, so the vertical arrows are equalities. Now we consider the diagram with exact rows and columns:

$$
\begin{CD}
  @.   0      @.   0         @.   0 \\
@.     @VVV        @VVV           @VVV\\
0 @>>> \color{red}0@>>> E(K)[m] @>(!)>> \tilde E(k)[m] @>>> 0 \\
@.     @VVV        @VVV           @VVV\\
0 @>>> E_1(K) @>>> E(K)    @>>> \tilde E(k) @>>> 0 \\
@.     @VV m V     @VV m V        @VV m V\\
0 @>>> E_1(K) @>>> E(K)    @>>> \tilde E(k) @>>> 0 \\
@.     @VVV        @VVV         @VVV\\
  @.   \vdots  @.   \vdots @.   \vdots  
\end{CD}
$$

(A diagram chasing or other arguments should show now that the map marked $(!)$ is a bijection.)

The red zero entry is insured in its column by Proposition 3.1. (a).